# AbstractController::DoubleRenderError in Home#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting the following error message. I have researched other posts but in my case there is no other render partial being called so I am unsure as to why I am getting this error...

```
Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/home/index.html.erb where
line #11 raised:

Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action.
Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most
once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate
execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after
redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and
return".
```

Extracted source (around line #7):

```
      image_tag(user.avatar, class: 'avatar-circle')
     else
      render partial: 'shared/avatar', locals: { user: user }
     end   
   end 
 end
```

Here is my code:

app/controllers/home_controller.rb

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  include UsersHelper
  helper_method :show_avatar

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end
end
```

app/controllers/concerns/users_helper.rb

```
module UsersHelper

  def show_avatar(user)
    if user.avatar?
      image_tag(user.avatar, class: 'avatar-circle')
    else
      render partial: 'shared/avatar', locals: { user: user }
    end
  end
end
```

app/views/home/index.html.erb

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <%= image_tag post.picture.url %>
      <div class="caption">
        <%= show_avatar(post.user) %>
        <p><strong><%= post.user.full_name %></strong> - <%= post.description %></p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The only thing I can think is that the partial is being called within the loop for each post, but surely this can't be the issue?

Comment: Might this be helpful: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/53487#30113 You don't **render** from a helper, but rather **return a value**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't render html in a helper method, you have to build it.

```
def show_avatar(user)
  if user.avatar?
    image_tag(user.avatar, class: 'avatar-circle')
  else
    render partial: 'shared/avatar', locals: { user: user }
  end
end
```

Try change the code in `else` statement to something similar to template `shared/avatar`:

```
content_tag(:div, 'something', class: 'whatever')
```

Or you can **move the logic** to `shared/avatar` to handle when `user.avatar?`